# Dealing with a single-qoute issue. Possibly related to Apple users?

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a text area in my form that users generally copy-and-paste text into from their word document, as they prepare it beforehand. I am having issues with a single-quotes, but not all of them. If I am not mistaking, I do believe that its some sort of a different characters possibly from Mac side of things.

When saving to database, characters are escaped so I don't get `&rsquo;` or something like that, but the quote itself is not "regular" one, it comes up as don’t instead on don't (*see the different in quote?*) It does not cause issues anywhere else in the code, but I do have fpdf export where that quote shows us as donâ€™t and I don't know how to address this issue.

I would much rather "convert" the characters to regular format before they are saved, then to deal with them retroactively during fpdf export. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem.

Comment: See also: [UTF-8 all the way through](//stackoverflow.com/q/279170) and [FPDF utf-8 encoding (HOW-TO)](//stackoverflow.com/q/6334134)

Comment: MS frequently applies something they dubiously call "smart quotes" which convert plain `'` and `"` into the angled versions `’` and `“` which are either UTF8 or cp1252 special characters. In your case they are UTF8, so read the links @mario has posted.